# Why is my html and js not being updating when I build cordova browser?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, cordova, apache-cordova

I'm simply changing some text in the index.html in www and then when I build for browser and check the platforms/browser/www/index.html file nothing has been changed. I had also tried removing the browser platform and re-adding it and it still doesn't get updated. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed on the web browser that the original `index.html` in `www/` has changed ? If so then double check that the build process (for example `cordova run android`) executes without any errors.

Answer (score -2):

1, Check if you really reload (F5) the current page.

2, You realy save changes to this file and reload? ( typicaly read/write permition when you save file i diferent path, save and open file again and check changes)

3, When you change JS , most browsers sometimes remembers the previous version. In Chrome just (Shift + Ctrl + I) or right click on mouse last "Inspect Element". Go to Source , Find your JS file and refresh the page.

4, Check that you not change a part that can not be seen (display:none div, under div and outhers ).

For outher option I nead more information.

Comment: i'm just adding a s to the end of device ready. and i'm opening up the direct html file in the projects folder with a txt editor and its not being changed so it's not a cache issue.